# Boost Spirit kwd parser in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi, boost-mpl

I'm using Boost 1.57 with Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to upgrade my project to Visual Studio 2013 but i'm having some problem with the boost Spirit parser.
Seem to me that the *kwd* parser is broken somehow. The following code compiles correctly in Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_kwd.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_keywords.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
using boost::phoenix::ref;
using boost::spirit::repository::qi::kwd;

template <typename Iterator>
bool difference(Iterator first, Iterator last, double& n) {
    bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
             //the grammar
             (kwd("A")[double_[ref(n) += _1]] /
              kwd("B")[double_ [ref(n) -= _1]]),
                              boost::spirit::ascii::space);
    if (first != last) return false;
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::string str("A 1 B 2");
    double n=0;
    std::cout << "Full parse: " << difference(str.begin(), str.end(), n) << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "A - B = " << n <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get wnen i try to compile it with Visual Studio 2013 are (among the many):

```
 Error  3   error C3203: 'type' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T2', expected a real type   ... fold_impl.hpp   
 Error  4   error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::apply<boost::fusion::detail::apply_transform_result<boost::spirit::repository::qi::detail::string_keywords<Elements,boost::mpl::filter_view<Elements,boost::spirit::repository::qi::is_kwd_parser<boost::mpl::_>>,boost::mpl::filter_view<boost::mpl::vector2<boost::mpl::integral_c<T,0>,boost::mpl::integral_c<T,1>>,boost::spirit::repository::qi::keywords<Elements,Modifiers>::is_kwd_parser_filter<boost::mpl::_>>,boost::array<bool,2>,Modifiers>::build_char_type_sequence<StringKeywords>::element_char_type>,boost::spirit::repository::qi::kwd_parser<Subject,const char (&),boost::spirit::qi::make_directive_internal<T1,Subject,Modifiers,boost::mpl::false_>::iterator_type,boost::spirit::has_modifier<Modifiers,boost::spirit::tag::char_code_base<CharClass>>,Distinct>,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>'   ... value_of_impl.hpp
```

Is this a bug of Boost? 
Is there any way to get this code to compile in Visual Studio 2013? 
(of course my real project is much bigger than this, it would be a problem to rewrite all the grammar)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly not MSVC specific. Here's **[clang stumbling](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a43f6ddcab617c5b)** (I removed the uses of namespaces that _will_ introduce ambiguities that may silently wreak havoc). [gcc does the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb4bdda2ce634261).

Comment: I guess it is compiler version dependent: gcc 4.7.1 on my pc compiles it without a warning.

Comment: indeed. See my answer explaining that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the mpl/fusion libraries have shifted to no longer expecting to TR1 result-of protocol.

This has everything to do with the fact that compilers at large have implemented decltype support, and in fact

- BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE has become the default boost config for most compilers
- Phoenix V3 has become the default for Spirit in recent versions

I verified that your particular sample does compile on clang when you insert this line at the top:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3693f5295cb2d8ff)**

**Actually** this still represents a problem that should be reported to the Spirit mailing list, IMO as TR1 protocol will certainly be obsoleted in the future.

In the meantime, I suggest to use TR1 as a fallback only:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE_WITH_TR1_FALLBACK
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/799b443cb4f1092b)** too.

#### *NOTE*

In order to compile with VS2013, I had to *also* add the following define

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it definitely works. I'll report it on the Boost mailing list, i couldn't find the solution on the documentation in the first place and it took me (and you) some time to solve it.

Comment: It's not about the time taken, to me. To me it's about future proofing this feature :) Thanks for the feedback