# Compiling boost::spirit with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to compile version 1.57 of boost's spirit using Visual Studio 2013 update 4. The following simple program yields many errors and warnings.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
int main()
{return 0;}
```

**What is going on?**

The compiler command line has the following options:

> /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MTd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Za /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Grammar.pch"

The most common warnings are

> Warning   1   warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored   X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\detail\preprocessed\pass_through_impl.hpp 40  1   Grammar

and

> Warning   79  warning C4224: nonstandard extension used : formal parameter 'expr' was previously defined as a type    X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\debug.hpp   126 1   Grammar

Some of the errors are:

> Error 195 error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'expr_param'  X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\arg.hpp   179 1   Grammar
>   Error   196 error C2065: 'expr_param' : undeclared identifier   X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\arg.hpp   179 1   Grammar
>   Error   197 error C2977: 'boost::proto::result_of::value' : too many template arguments X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\arg.hpp   179 1   Grammar
>   Error   198 error C2955: 'boost::proto::result_of::value' : use of class template requires template argument list   X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\arg.hpp   179 1   Grammar
>   Error   199 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expr_param' X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\arg.hpp   182 1   Grammar
>   Error   200 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expr_param' X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\detail\preprocessed\make.hpp  69  1   Grammar
>   Error   201 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expr_param' X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  73  1   Grammar
>   Error   202 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\detail\preprocessed\poly_function_funop.hpp 14  1   Grammar
>   Error   203 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\detail\preprocessed\poly_function_funop.hpp 14  1   Grammar
>   Error   204 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::tr1_result_of (Env)>'   X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\env.hpp   367 1   Grammar
>   Error   205 error C2504: 'type' : base class undefined  X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\env.hpp   368 1   Grammar
>   Error   206 error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of 'boost::proto::result_of::has_env_var'    X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  189 1   Grammar
>   Error   207 error C2975: 'C' : invalid template argument for 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c', expected compile-time constant expression X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  192 1   Grammar
>   Error   208 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c,boost::proto::result_of::env_var>' X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  192 1   Grammar
>   Error   209 error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'type'    X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  193 1   Grammar
>   Error   210 error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  193 1   Grammar
>   Error   211 error C2977: 'boost::remove_reference' : too many template arguments    X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  193 1   Grammar
>   Error   212 error C2955: 'boost::remove_reference' : use of class template requires template argument list  X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  193 1   Grammar
>   Error   213 error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation X:.libraries\boost\boost\proto\transform\when.hpp  194 1   Grammar

Comment: What is the first warning / error?

Comment: Also, perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126177/boost-spirit-kwd-parser-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @BillLynch: warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning

Comment: I tried adding `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1` and `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the beginning but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

and one of

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE // or
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 // or
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1_WITH_DECLTYPE_FALLBACK
```

> **Note** It's crucial to define these before first inclusion of *any* boost header. This includes any `stdafx.h` if you have one

If any of the combinations result in success, report the bug at the [spirit-general](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/spirit-general-f2672582.html) mailing list or [Boost Trac](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/tickets.html). It could well be a missing/inappropriate compiler feature detection thing (I'm wondering about `constexpr`, or other features where MSVC might be starting support for things)